# Why doesn't break get me out of ruby -n loop?

Tags: ruby

This website says

> The -n switch acts as though the code you pass to Ruby was wrapped in
>   the following:
>
> ```
> while gets
>   # code here
> end
> ```

But if I type `ruby -n`

and type `return` or `exit` or `quit` or `break`, why don't they get me out of the infinite while loop above?

But somehow `end` did it:

```
$ ruby -n
return
break
exit
quit
end
-:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `ruby -n`, Ruby is expecting two distinct files from STDIN: the script (since you didn't provide a Ruby script name in an argument, nor a Ruby expression in `-e`), and the file to process (due to `-n`). Thus, `return` won't stop your script simply because, at that point, the script is not yet running; `return` *is* the script, and you'd need to wait till you start inputting the next file for the `return` to work.

Try this:

```
$ ruby -n
puts "ECHO: #{$_}"
return if $. == 2
<Ctrl-D>
hello
# => ECHO: hello
world
# => ECHO: world
$
```

Ctrl-D on Unix/OSX (Ctrl-Z on Windows) will indicate the end of file, so Ruby will continue inputting the second one. The first two lines thus are the script. After you've ended that file, the next line (`hello`) serves as the input for the script, and the script will echo it back. The next line (`world`) continues the input for the script, but now the line counter `$.` shows it's the second line of the input, `return` executes, and the script ends, as it should.

Comment: Thank you, you explain it in a very clear, logical and thorough way!